# How to prevent Ubuntu automatically changing display language

Tags: 14.04, system-language

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, my location is France. Ubuntu change displaying language automatically to french. I set it to English, it works for a moment and then it set automatically to french again.

is there any file to edit to prevent automatically language changing??

Answer (score 3):

First, go to **System Settings** → **Language Support** and in **Langage** tab, apply system wide **English**:

[image: Language Support]

In **Regional Formats** apply system wide your favorite **English**:

[image: Regional Formats]

Second, go to **System Settings** → **User Accounts** and select **English** as your language:

[image: User Accounts]

After all of these settings, a re-login is necessary.

Comment: I did exactly like that, after 3 days in come back to french because it detect my location, your answer didn't work, it should be  somewhere where disabling automatic language setting using geographic location